# PySpark: Counting Word Pairs and Individual Words

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do some basic text analysis using PySpark.

To start this problem, I load a text file containing shakespears sonnets to an RDD. The output should be an RDD containing tuples as shown below:

```
(word_pair, count_of_word_pair, word_1_count, word_2_count)
```

where word_1 and word_2 are the individual words that make up the word_pair.

So far, I am able to correctly generate one RDD that contains the individual unique words and the count of the number of lines that they occur on and another RDD containing word_pairs (order matters) and counts:

```
distFile = sc.textFile("Shakespeare.txt")

    tokens = (
        distFile.map(simple_tokenize)
        .flatMap(set)
        .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
    )

    token_pairs = (
        distFile.map(simple_tokenize)
        .flatMap(lambda x: itertools.permutations(x, 2))
        .filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1])
        .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

**Note:** *simple_tokenize* is a function that sets all characters to lowercase and splits the sentence on each line into a list of words.

Sample outputs below:
First 10 Elements of tokens:

```
('shakespeare', 38),
  ('we', 3125),
  ('fairest', 42),
  ('increase', 28),
  ('creatures', 38),
  ('die', 461),
  ('rose', 68),
  ("beauty's", 30),
  ('thereby', 26),
  ('never', 996)]
```

First 10 elements of token_pairs:

```
[('the', 'sonnets', 2),
  ('sonnets', 'the', 2),
  ('by', 'william', 39),
  ('william', 'by', 39),
  ('from', 'desire', 4),
  ('fairest', 'creatures', 1),
  ('fairest', 'we', 1),
  ('fairest', 'increase', 1),
  ('creatures', 'fairest', 1),
  ('creatures', 'we', 4)],
```

I am very stuck in that I do not understand how to combine these different counts in the same RDD (as per the required output). As I understand it, I cannot perform any type of key loop between RDDs inside of a map function (or that I can't do it at all unless I collect one of them). Is this correct?

How can I get the desired output without having to store anything as a local variable in Python?

Comment: Can you please post examples of output of each of the RDDs you generate? in order to give you a detailed answer? (ideally two outputs you would like to combine) The idea would be to map both your RDDs to have similar keys then apply a join operator between the two RDDs in order to combine them. With examples of outputs you generated I will be able to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: @AhlamAIS I have updated the original question to include sample data. Thank you.

Comment: @AhlamAIS My current solution now is to simply join the token_pairs and token RDDs twice, using one word of the token_pairs key each time. Not sure how efficient this is, but it's functional.